# How to compute a directory's SHA param without git?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github

I want to compute the SHA param like GitHub API 'v3/repos/contents/', but I don't want to depend on git.

For Example, https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/contents/.

```
{
    "name": "fixtures",
    "path": "fixtures",
    "sha": "5eca527b968f1c42a2468bc98f96f02ea770b607",
```

How to compute the SHA param of a directory?

Comment: This isn't as straightforward as you might expect. Why do you want to do this, and especially why without Git? What's the goal here? You may have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).